# How to overide PasswordInAsync for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have this unique requirement to login to MVC ASP.NET app by adding extra "Tenant Code" next to Username/email and password.

We've created a few class below:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String Address { get; set; }

    public String Postcode { get; set; }

    public String State { get; set; }

    public String LandLineNo { get; set; }

    public String MobileNo { get; set; }

    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

}

public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String Code { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastDateModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

We've added properties in class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

```
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

and added on class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }
```

The only that we can think of is to override the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync is that right? How to achieve this?

I'm appreciated your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think overriding the `PasswordSignInAsync` is going to be useful since its signature doesn't take over the user entity. It only takes over **username**, **password**, **isPersistent** & **shouldLockout** so you don't have any access to any tenant info. If you tried to check for the tenant info buy the username you may end up with multple accounts.

I would recommend creating your own method in a class that derives from the `SignInManager`. Get this to check the user and tenant info and call `SignInAsync` or `SignInOrTwoFactor` (if you're using 2 factor auth).

If you get a bit lost, have a look at the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` assembly, in your decompiler of choice, and check what those methods are doing.